# Определение браузера

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как средствами jQuery определить браузер (FireFox в частности)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
if($.browser.safari&&!$.browser.mozilla&&!$.browser.msie&&!$.browser.opera){alert("Вы пользуетесь Safari!");}   
if($.browser.opera){alert("Вы пользуетесь Opera!");}
if($.browser.mozilla){alert("Вы пользуетесь Mozilla!");}
if($.browser.msie){alert("Вы пользуетесь Internet Explorer!");}
if($.browser.webkit&&!$.browser.safari){alert("Вы пользуетесь webkit!");}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Уже нет, [$.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) удален в 1.9

Answer (score 2):

сейчас актуально писать $.support

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы (например, с минимальным примером, и, возможно, с отсылкой к *официальной* документации).

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Неактуально начиная с версии 1.9